# Unable to Ping Remote Database Server from Home WiFi Network

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing

I am encountering a network connectivity issue when attempting to ping a remote database server from my home WiFi network. The server, identified by the IP address 192.168.100.91, is accessible via a VPN connection provided by my workplace. However, when I attempt to ping the server from my Linux system while connected to my home WiFi network, I consistently receive a "Destination Host Unreachable" error.

I'm using openvpn for the vpn connectivity. When I connect to alternative networks, such as using mobile data or other WiFi networks, I am able to successfully ping the remote database server without encountering any errors.

Here are the steps I have taken so far to troubleshoot the issue. I'm no networking expert so I followed general troubleshooting:

- Verified network configuration on my system, ensuring proper connection to the home WiFi network.
- Checked router configuration for any firewall rules or access control settings blocking traffic to the server IP address. (I don't have any such thing setup which might be causing any issues)
- Restarted network services and rebooted my system to ensure all configurations are refreshed.
- Tested connectivity to other devices on the home network, which was successful.
- Verified VPN configuration, ensuring correct server address and authentication credentials.

Despite these efforts, I am still unable to ping the remote database server specifically from my home WiFi network. The issue seems isolated to this network, as connectivity is established when using alternative networks.

I am seeking assistance to identify and resolve this network connectivity issue. Any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your home ISP perhaps blocking VPNs?

Comment: What is your local IP address (and subnet mask) when connected to your home WiFi? `192.168.100.X` is not uncommon for home networks, and could overlap with the VPN routing for example. Even if it's not the same `.100.X`, the workplace may have an overlapping network somewhere on their end as well

Comment: @Cpt.Whale My local IP Address is `.100.X` indeed. What are my options?

Comment: Log into your home WiFi router and change its DHCP settings to use a different network. The steps for that can differ depending on your router. For example, set DHCP pool to `192.168.0.[100-200]` and update the default gateway to `192.168.0.1`. You may need to set the LAN address to `192.168.0.1` as well. Then remember to disconnect+reconnect your device (you should get a `.0.X` IP), and your VPN should start working better